# Adding all combinations of numbers from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I'm tackling this problem on coderbyte... the instructions are to define a function ArrayAdditionI(arr), that takes the array of numbers in arr, and returns true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest (otherwise return false). For example, ArrayAdditionI([4,6,23,10,1,3]) returns true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23.

I wrote the following function, and it seems to work, although I don't think it's quite as concise as I'd like it to be. I wanted to see if there is a way to make this shorter and sweeter without getting into any complicated aspects of JavaScript, i.e. just using loops and addition as I did here. Any suggestions are welcome...

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 

// let's find the largest number

var i,
    j,
    k,
    largest,
    result,
    length = arr.length - 1,
    sorted = [];

sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a - b});
largest = sorted.pop();

for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    result = sorted[i];
    if (result === largest) {
        return true;
    }
    for (j = i + 1; j < length; j += 1) {
        result = sorted[i] + sorted[j];
        if (result === largest) {
            return true;
        }
        for (k = j + 1; k < length; k += 1) {
            result = sorted[i] + sorted[j] + sorted[k];
            if (result === largest) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Consider posting at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

you can loop with do while also.. the below method isnot the fastest... and i am assuming you only need to know if the sum will equal to the largest number and you don't need to print out...  like.. 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23.

```
 function ArrayAdditionI(arr) {

  arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a - b;});
  // the largest number in the array.. 
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);

//  a helper function to find the sum of an aray.. 
var arrSum = function(array) {return array.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b;}); };  

// creating subArrays..
var subArrs = [], subArr, mask, total = Math.pow(2, arr.length);

for(mask = 0;mask<total; mask++){
subArr =  [] ;
 i = arr.length - 1 ;

 do{
if( (mask & (1 << i)) !== 0) {
              subArr.push(arr[i]) ; }
        }
  while(i--);

  // since we only need the sum 
  if( subArr.length >= 2){
    if(arrSum(subArr) > largest) {
      break; 
    }

          subArrs.push(arrSum(subArr)); } 
    }

  // remove dupes..
subArrs = subArrs.filter(function(array, pos) {
    return subArrs.indexOf(array) == pos;}) ;

  console.log("Largest : " + largest);
  console.log( subArrs);

  // search if  largest number exsists in the array... 
  for(var l in subArrs) {
    if ( subArrs[+l] == largest) {
     return true ; 
    }
  }

return false; 
}

console.log(ArrayAdditionI([4,6,23,10,1,3]) );
```

[you can see it here..](http://jsbin.com/UCUWiheC/5/edit?js,console)